# Fabric scripts to install Hadoop on a cluster of machines?

Tags: hadoop, installation, hadoop-yarn

I am beginning to install hadoop on a cluster. I have ssh access to these machines and I have already installed fabric on them. I was wondering if someone has already written a fabfile to install and deploy hadoop to a cluster easily.
I found this project [0]; but this is written for deploying over AWS instances. I was looking for something where I can just fill in the IPs of my machines and then execute a set of fab commands to bring up the cluster.

[0] http://www.alexjf.net/blog/distributed-systems/hadoop-yarn-installation-definitive-guide/#ec2-deployment-with-fabric-script

Comment: just wondering what would be the purpose of installing hadoop on ec2 instances? the AWS EMR service provides this embedded, only few clicks and done :) or maybe this script was actually born before EMR

Answer (score 2):

I'm AlexJF, the author of the scripts you linked.

The scripts you reference can also be used outside EC2. You just need to configure, as you requested, the list of hosts and configurations on the top of the [fabfile.py](https://github.com/AlexJF/fabric-scripts/blob/master/hadoop-yarn/fabfile.py). Be sure to set `EC2 = False` (which just happens to be the default).

You'll then have [several useful commands](http://www.alexjf.net/blog/distributed-systems/hadoop-yarn-installation-definitive-guide/#other-deployment-scripts) available to you.